# AWS EMR JupiterLab, how to install packages?

Tags: python, jupyter

This is perennial question but on EMR seems that things get more complicated. I can import sys,pyspark that is OK.
But

```
!{sys.executable} -m pip install boto3
```

Got

```
invalid syntax (<stdin>, line 1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    !{sys.executable} -m pip install boto3
    ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    echo $PATH
invalid syntax (<stdin>, line 1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    echo $PATH
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If PATH is not recognised how does import work?

How to fix install?

Answer (score 0):

I changed kernel from Pyspark to Python3,now works OK.